# wkhtmltopdf TimeOut Error

Tags: javascript, wkhtmltopdf

I have a node application which allows users to create PDFs from HTML.

The application uses wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3-dev-79ff51e (with patched qt) via node-wkhtmltopdf.

Sometimes I get the error:

```
Error: Exit with code 1 due to network error: TimeoutError
at Socket.<anonymous> (/srv/exporter/utils/wkhtmltopdf.js:117:19)
at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
at Pipe.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Why does wkhtmltopdf require network access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Font Libraries** which need to be downloaded during PDF creation.

Some PDFs require font libraries and when `WKHTMLTOPDF` tried downloading those libraries the network connection timed out because of incorrect credentials.

By coincidence some small PDFs did not require external fonts and the error was not present.